# ORDER BY causes operand type clash

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that works fine as it is, but I wish to add sorting to it. This is working fine:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAll]
    @SID NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @DID NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @KID NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @name NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @sortExpression NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @sortDirection NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @DateFrom DATETIME = NULL,
    @DateTo DATETIME = NULL

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
    WHERE
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @SID IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%sID=' + @SID + '%' END
    AND
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @DID IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%DID=' + @DID + '%' END
    AND
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @KID IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%CID=' + @KID + '%' END
    AND
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @name IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%name=' + @name + '%' END
    AND
        [Timestamp] BETWEEN ISNULL(@DateFrom, [Timestamp]) AND ISNULL(@DateTo, [Timestamp])
    AND
        [SID] = ISNULL(@SID, [SID])
    AND
        [CID] = ISNULL(@KID, [CID])
END
```

Then I tried to add the sorting like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAll]
    @SID NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @DID NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @KID NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @name NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @sortExpression NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @sortDirection NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @DateFrom DATETIME = NULL,
    @DateTo DATETIME = NULL

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MyTable]   -- This is line 24
    WHERE
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @SID IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%sID=' + @SID + '%' END
    AND
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @DID IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%DID=' + @DID + '%' END
    AND
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @KID IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%CID=' + @KID + '%' END
    AND
        [Message] LIKE CASE WHEN @name IS NULL THEN [Message] ELSE '%name=' + @name + '%' END
    AND
        [Timestamp] BETWEEN ISNULL(@DateFrom, [Timestamp]) AND ISNULL(@DateTo, [Timestamp])
    AND
        [SID] = ISNULL(@SID, [SID])
    AND
        [CID] = ISNULL(@KID, [CID])
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'asc' THEN
        CASE
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'ID' THEN [ID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'Timestamp' THEN [Timestamp]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'Message' THEN [Message]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'PID' THEN [PID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'CID' THEN [CID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'SID' THEN [SID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'OType' THEN [OType]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'OID' THEN [OID]
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'desc' THEN
        CASE
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'ID' THEN [ID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'Timestamp' THEN [Timestamp]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'Message' THEN [Message]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'PID' THEN [PID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'CID' THEN [CID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'SID' THEN [SID]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'OType' THEN [OType]
            WHEN @sortExpression = 'OID' THEN [OID]
        END
    END DESC
END
```

And that gives me the following errors:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetAll, Line 24
Operand type clash: decimal is incompatible with datetime2
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetAll, Line 24
Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with datetime2
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetAll, Line 24
Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with datetime2
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetAll, Line 24
Operand type clash: decimal is incompatible with datetime2
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure GetAll, Line 24
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with datetime2
```

Does anyone know why this is? I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

P.S. my columns and parameters are more properly named, but I've censored them for this post <3

Comment: You can't do it that way... The returned values of the `CASE` must be of the same type... So you can't use a `CASE ... WHEN` to do a dynamic `ORDER BY`. I do know that it is a bad word, but dynamic sql is normally used.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this article. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a single type.  So, your types are not compatible.  Instead of trying to make them compatible, use separate expressions for each column:

```
(CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'asc' AND @sortExpression = 'ID' THEN [ID] END) ASC,
(CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'asc' AND @sortExpression = 'Timestamp' THEN [Timestamp] END) ASC,
. . .
(CASE WHEN @sortDirection = 'desc' AND @sortExpression = 'OID' THEN [OID] END) DESC
```

The non-matching conditions all return `NULL`, so they don't affect the ordering.

Another alternative would be to use dynamic SQL.